# Скрыть\показать div

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

У меня есть N-ое количество таких элементов на странице:

```
<div class="main">
<a class="text">Любой текст</a>
<div class="buttons">кнопки</div> //этот элемент скрыт по-умолчанию.
</div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на

```
<a class="text">Любой текст</a>
```

Показывался div buttons . Причем только тот, который в данном блоке main.

Я нашел примерный скриптик и чуть [подстроил под себя](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6frj/) , но проблема в том, что это открывает кнопки всех элементов. 
Как это поменять?

[Ссылка на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6frj/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Еще вариант, который точно работает в хроме:

```
$(".text").click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.main').find('.buttons').show();
});
```

UPDATE

```
$(".text").click(function() {
e = $(this).closest('.main').find('.buttons');
    if(!e.is(':visible')) {
    $('.buttons').hide();
    e.show();
}
});
```

Понял так.

Comment: @Равнодушный,
О да!) Он работает. 
Тогда можете еще подсказать, как скрыть элемент, который был показан, чтобы при клике на другой main открылся новый. Ну закрыть один, открыть другой.

Comment: И еще вопрос сразу, как избавиться от перехода вверх страницы, когда ссылка вида  href='#' ?

Comment: `return false;`

В конце обработчика или 

`function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}`

в начале. Тут на любителя.

Лично я предпочитаю не использовать пустых ссылок.

Comment: Наиогромнейшее спасибо!) 
Я сначала с одним кодом мудил 3 дня. Не понимал в чем ошибка. Оказалось, что он просто в хроме не работает. Сегодня вот подумал оперу врубить и разозлился сильно)
Вы очень помогли!

Answer (score 7):

```
$(".text").click(function(){   
  $(this).next(".buttons").show();
});
```

Comment: Когда написалось, что root ответил, то я даже растерялся..
Спасибо)

Answer (score 7):

```
$(".text").click(function(){   
  $(this).next(".buttons").toggle();
});
```

Будет и открываться и закрываться, как указано в заголовке.

Comment: данный вариант не работает в некоторых браузерах, если я не ошибаюсь..

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов по идее это кроссбраузерное решение, так что должно работать в каждом браузере.

Comment: Единственный неизвратный ответ) плюсую

Answer (score 5):

[getElementsByClass()](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#8-getelementsbyclass).

```
<head>
<script>
if (document.getElementsByClassName) {

    getElementsByClass = function (classList, node) {
        return (node || document).getElementsByClassName(classList)
    }

} else {

    getElementsByClass = function (classList, node) {
        var node = node || document,
            list = node.getElementsByTagName('*'),
            length = list.length,
            classArray = classList.split(/\s+/),
            classes = classArray.length,
            result = [],
            i, j
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < classes; j++) {
                if (list[i].className.search('\\b' + classArray[j] + '\\b') != -1) {
                    result.push(list[i])
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <p class="text">Любой текст</p>
    <div class="buttons">кнопки</div>
</div>
<p class="text">Любой текст</p>
<script>
    function fn() {
        getElementsByClass('buttons')[0].style.display = 'none'

    }

    if (document.addEventListener) {

        getElementsByClass('text')[1].addEventListener('click', fn, false);
    } else {
        getElementsByClass('text')[1].attachEvent('onclick', fn)
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Кажется не работает, не пойму что куда пихать(сделал как у Вас)

Comment: @koza4ok , а есть еще варианты? А то этот у меня что-то не работает.
А тот, что написал @root , не работает в хроме. А это плохо.

Comment: у меня все работает.У вас может Dom другой.Откройте firebug.Что он пишет?

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов на чистом html...

```html
<details>
    <summary class="text">Любой текст</summary>
    <button class="buttons">Кнопка</button>
</details>
<details>
    <summary class="text">Любой текст</summary>
    <button class="buttons">Кнопка</button>
</details>
<details open="open">
    <summary class="text">Любой текст</summary>
    <button class="buttons">Кнопка</button>
</details>
```